# Submit button in recursive treeview in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a recursive treeview with checkboxes using React JS. I want to make a form and submit button in order to get the checked values but I am not getting where to insert the submit button in the form. So far my code generates a submit button with each node.

```
toggle = () => {
    this.setState(
      {visible: !this.state.visible}
    );
  };

  render() {
    var childNodes;

    if (this.props.node.childNodes != null) {
      childNodes = this.props.node.childNodes.map(function(node, index) {
        return <li key={index}><Treeview node={node} /></li>
      });
    }

    var style;
    if (!this.state.visible) {
      style = {display: "none"};
    }

    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          {this.props.node.title}
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.toggle}/>
        </label>
        <ul style={style}>
          {childNodes}
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is the issue with having the submit input where it currently is?

Comment: It creates Submit buttons with each tree node. I am trying to make submit button at the end of the treeview yet a part of form.

Comment: What is TreeView?  Is that the component we're looking at?  If so, it looks like you're doing a recursive render.  If that's the case you'll either need a way (like a prop) to know now to render the the submit button, or just render the checks recursively and the form and submit outside of it all.

Comment: Yes, TreeView is the component which I am rendering recursively. I want a Submit button at the end of the treeview, i.e at the end of the form but I am not sure where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to go about doing what you want.  One (Ex 1) would be having a structure with two components/methods, one for the form and another for the recursive checkbox structure.

Another (Ex 2) would to be to use props to conditionally render some portions.

**Ex 1**

```
function TreeView (props) {
  var childNodes;

  if (props.node.childNodes != null) {
    childNodes = props.node.childNodes.map(function(node, index) {
      return <li key={index}><Treeview node={node} /></li>
    });
  }

  var style;
  if (!props.visible) {
    style = {display: "none"};
  }

  return (
    <ul style={style}>
      {childNodes}
    </ul>
  );
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle () {
    this.setState(
      {visible: !this.state.visible}
    );
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          {this.props.node.title}
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.toggle}/>
        </label>

        <TreeView node={props.node} visible={this.state.visible} />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**Ex 2**

```
class Treeview extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle () {
    this.setState(
      {visible: !this.state.visible}
    );
  };

  render () {
    var childNodes;

    if (this.props.node.childNodes != null) {
      childNodes = this.props.node.childNodes.map(function(node, index) {
        return <li key={index}><Treeview node={node} childTree /></li>
      });
    }

    var style;
    if (!this.state.visible) {
      style = {display: "none"};
    }

    if (this.props.childTree) {
      return (
        <ul>
          {childNodes}
        </ul>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <form>
          <label>
            {this.props.node.title}
            <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.toggle}/>
          </label>
          <ul style={style}>
            {childNodes}
          </ul>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the second approach because I am making form in the same react component but I am kind of still getting buttons with each node

Comment: Oops there was a typo.  I forgot the `this`. I've updated the example to say `if (this.props.childTree)`  Be sure you add the `childTree` prop  in your recursive render `<Treeview node={node} chidTree />`